# The correct Group By statement for my tables

Tags: sql, group-by, sas

First of all, I am using SAS. So the solution can be in sas data set or simply SQL statement

My original data is table A. However, I want to transform it into the Final table which is on the right.
[image: Screenshot]

As you all can see from the image link that I attached, I just couldn't think of the logic for it.

Comment: Please always include something you've tried.

Answer (score 5):

I see the SAS programmers are still sleeping.  This has the advantage of not having to refer to the variables other than the group variable(s).

```
data want;
   update have(obs=0) have;
   by datetime;
   run;
```

Comment: Elegant and very SAS-y solution.  Cudos.

Answer (score 2):

use aggregated  function which ignore null values

```
 select Datetime,max(status) as status ,max(option) as option,
max(age) as age,max(Height) as Height,max(Bloodtype) as Bloodtype
from tableA 
group by Datetime
```

Answer (score 1):

use aggregation:

```
select datetime,max(status) status,max(option) option, max(age) age,max(height) height,max(bloodtype) bloodtype
from tablename
group by datetime
```

Answer (score 1):

`max` and `min` ignore `null`s, so if you have a single non-`null` value each group, `max` (or `min`) will just return that value:

```
SELECT   datetime, MAX(option), MAX(age), MAX(height), MAX(bloodtype)
FROM     a
GROUP BY datetime
```